# What layer do Nymphs spawn on?

Tags: terraria

The internet is full of inconsistent tips about Nymph farming. So here's an easy one.

Do Nymphs spawn in the underground layer or the cavern layer?

Comment: As an extra tip, you can use a Lifeform Analyzer while carrying some Hunter potions and Binoculars. Once you see the Lifeform Analyzer show that there's a Lost Girl nearby you stand still, activate the Hunter Potion and use your Binoculars to scan the area around you. It's easier to find them in Pre-Hardmode, and while using a Drill Containment Unit. Be sure to not attack it before she turns into a Nymp, or you will get no loot.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

They spawn in the Cavern layer.

I have often found them near marble but they are not part of that spawn.. Most likely I slow down long enough around marble while being careful just to notice the Nymph.

Best thing? Get a rare creature detector (Lifeform Analyzer) from the Traveling Merchant and just keep an eye out for them.

Comment: faster than me by a minute.. xD

Comment: @ExplosionsPlus I had to look up the name of the life form analyzer :D I thought it was a scanner, hehe.

Answer (score 8):

### [Nymphs](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Nymph) [image: The Nymph] [image: The Lost Girl]

Nymphs are **rare** enemies that spawns as a Lost Girl the first time you see it. The spawn rate is **0.6%** in **Pre-Hardmode** and **0.1%** in **Hardmode**.

They are found in the **Caverns** and **not** in the **Underground**.

Answer (score 1):

Found in ice caves at cavern level. Better chance in pre-hardmode. To make a good farm in pre hardmode make a basic mob grinder but make it that you can walk through it and do not forgot do this 50 blocks above stone layer. 
Good Luck!
PlanteraKiller

Comment: The question is a bit old and already had an accepted answer. However others may check this question and be helped by your answer. With that said, welcome to Arqade and thank you for contributing =)